# How to take userinput as seperate characters?

Tags: c#

I want to take every character typed by the user as an individual value for eg if user types `Hello Wolrd` each character is stored seperately `H`,`E`,`L`,`L`,`O` so that i can convert characters from `A-G` into `1` `H-Q` into `2` and `R-Z` into `3` so output of `HELLO` results in: `21222`

Comment: Remember that a `string` is effectively just an array of `char`...

Comment: string.ToCharArray();

Comment: @DavidG `std::string` is much more then merely a `char` array. Else we would just use a `char` array ;)

Comment: @J.H.Bonarius thus his use of the word `effectively`

Answer (score 4):

You can use regular expressions:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

string input = "Hello Wolrd";
input = input.ToUpper();
input = Regex.Replace(input, "[A-G]", "1");
input = Regex.Replace(input, "[H-Q]", "2");
input = Regex.Replace(input, "[R-Z]", "3");
```

This sample code can be improved/optimized, but that should give you a simple starting point to meet your needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
var map = new Dictionary<char, char>() { { 'A', '1'}, {'B', '1'}, //etc };
var result = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char c in srcString) {
   char mappedChar;
   if (map.TryGetValue(c, out mappedChar))
      result.Append(mappedChar);
}
return result.ToString();
```

Comment: I would recommend the regular expression solution by @SegFault if you want more readable/maintable code.  You would use this solution if you needed super-highspeed (e.g. you were going to pass LOTS of strings through the same Dictionary lookup)